# Mongoose numerical ID increment when creating a new document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongo model as such:

```
module.exports = (Schema, ObjectId) => {
  return new Schema({
    objectid: ObjectId,
    creator: String,
    created: Date,
    updated: Date,
    script: String,
    html: String,
    template: Number
  });
};
```

Instead of giving the user `objectid` or `_id` which is long and difficult to remember, I will give the users `template` which is a numerical ID, such as: 1, 2, 3, 4...

The problem being, if I am doing this approach I must:

```
  const biggestTemplateRes = await db.templates
    .findOne()
    .sort({
      template: -1
    });
  if (biggestTemplateRes) {
    biggestTemplate = biggestTemplateRes.toObject().template;
  }
  ++biggestTemplate;
  console.log({ biggestTemplate });
  return db.templates.create({
    creator,
    created,
    updated,
    template: biggestTemplate,
    ...attrs
  });
```

search for the biggest template and then create a bigger one...which:

1. decrease the performance by adding one more query.
2. may have problem if the biggest template is deleted so the newly created template would have the same template number as the previously deleted one.

Problem two above can be solved with an additional collection/model of which I can use to maintain the sequence but it doesn't really solve problem 1...

Is it possible to let mongo know that I want template to be a numerical ID field with increment when creating a new document?

Answer (score 0):

ObjectId solves the exact problem you are describing with id generation. ObjectId are very likely to be globally unique and are generated on the client without talking to the database (or any centralized authority).

If you want to have sequential natural numbers as your ids, there must be some data store that tracks the highest used id and the application needs to interact with it (i.e. perform a roundtrip) to figure out the next id to use.

You can use MongoDB as your data store but you still need to perform a roundtrip to obtain the next id to use.

The reason why MongoDB does not provide this functionality out of the box like many relational databases do is because of sharding - when sharding is used the application is interacting with a subset of all servers and thus there isn't a central authority that can tell you which ids are used.